# Store contents of two lists as key-value pairs in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two Python lists. One list, called `area`, stores the areas of homes. Different homes may have the same area. Another list, called `price`, stores the corresponding prices of these homes. I want to create a dictionary called `priceDict`, whose keys are the unique areas of homes and whose values are lists of the prices of homes of the same area. For example, suppose `area = [1500, 500, 1500, 2000, 2500, 2000]`, `price = [30000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 50000, 45000]`. I would like to create the dictionary `priceDict = {1500: [30000, 20000], 500: [10000], 2000: [40000, 45000], 2500: [50000]}`.

I wrote the following Python code:

```
area = [1500, 500, 1500, 2000, 2500, 2000]
price = [30000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 50000, 45000]
priceDict = dict.fromkeys(area,[])
    
for houseArea in priceDict:
    for areaIndex in range(len(area)):
        if area[areaIndex] == houseArea:
            priceDict[houseArea].append(price[areaIndex])

print(priceDict)
```

However, when I executed the code, the output I got was:

```
{1500: [30000, 20000, 10000, 40000, 45000, 50000], 500: [30000, 20000, 10000, 40000, 45000, 50000], 2000: [30000, 20000, 10000, 40000, 45000, 50000], 2500: [30000, 20000, 10000, 40000, 45000, 50000]}
```

I would like to ask what's wrong with my code and how I can re-write my code so that it performs the intended function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) `[some_list] * number` and `dict.fromkeys(iterable, some_list)` contain the same problem.

Comment: What is the pattern to get these values: `priceDict = {1500: [30000, 20000], 500: [10000], 2000: [40000, 45000], 2500: [50000]}`. I can understand if the first element in one list is the key and the other first element of the other list is the value. But you are assigning 2 values to 1 key. How we know the pattern of your pair key-values?

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos For example, the elements with indices 0 and 2 in list ```area``` have the value 1500, therefore the elements with indices 0 and 2 in list ```price```, which are 30000 and 20000, are put into the same list that serves as the value of the key ```1500``` in the dictionary ```priceDict```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is here:

```
priceDict = dict.fromkeys(area,[])
```

This makes every key in `priceDict` share the same list.

The second problem is you are nesting for-loops rather than using a single for-loop and zipping to pair up your items:

```
priceDict = {}
for k, v in zip(area, price):
    priceDict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Note that `priceDict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)` is slightly inefficient because it creates an empty list on every iteration.  A more efficient way is to use a `defaultdict` of `list`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

priceDict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(area, price):
    priceDict[k].append(v)
```